# Is there a way to retrieve the URL from Reminders items?

Tags: macos, reminders

I use BusyCal, and have discovered that using Reminders causes anything in the URL field in BusyCal to vanish. However, it looks like the URL is still present in the Reminder. Is there any way to extract it, say from whatever on-disk file the Reminder is stored in? (Just clicking on it doesn’t give me the URL if it’s a `message:` URL, which it often is.)

Comment: Have you tried copy and pasting the url from Reminders.app?

Comment: How does one copy the url form Reminders.app?